# Copy mailbox to Public Folder. Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange-2003, public-folders

I want to be able to send all emails from an existing Exchange mailbox to a public folder. I am using Exchange 2003 and haven't found a clear way to do this. Anyone have any insight? I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: What I did was opened the email account in Outlook and copped the email into the Public Folder. Tested and saw it was showing up everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

When having it open in Outlook, you should be able to drag the 'Inbox' into the Public folder.